# Finger print scanner with webusb

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, fingerprint, webusb, digital-persona-sdk

Is possible to connected/paired usb finger print scanner with webusb (https://wicg.github.io/webusb)?

I have digital persona U.are.U 4500 and want to connect to browser (chrome) with react.js and get image file and can compare image

Comment: Do you have any development on this?

Comment: already work well now..

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Comment: @rusliAbdulgani how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

WebUSB is a generic API for communicating with USB devices and so supporting any particular device requires knowledge of the data protocol used to communicate with the device. Manufacturers may or may not provide public documentation for this protocol and so it is often necessary to reverse engineer it by observing the communication between the device and a closed-source driver. In the cases where an open-source driver is available then that can be a reference for building a Javascript application to control the device.

In the case of the DigitalPersona U.are.U 4500 it appears that the open-source libfprint library includes a driver for this series of devices: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/blob/master/libfprint/drivers/uru4000.c

This would be a good starting point for understanding how to communicate with the device.

Comment: This is certainly a good starting point, but the code is not exceptionally well structured. It's like trying to understand a foreign language using literature from excentric poets.