# Can a DigitalPersona USB fingerprint scanner be used directly in the browser using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fingerprint

I can access a DigitalPersona 4500 with the following code :

```
navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{ vendorId: 0x05ba }] })
.then(device => {
  console.log(device.productName);      // "VM56:3 U.are.U® 4500 Fingerprint Reader"
  console.log(device.manufacturerName); // "VM56:4 DigitalPersona, Inc."

  // ...

})
.catch(error => { console.error(error); });
```

Now, is it possible to open the device and start scanning?

(Disclaimer: I do not have access to the DP SDK because the devices I have access to were bought before I was hired, from some third party vendor and, after contacting them, they did not provide me with any support. The devices work just fine, so there are no plans to throw them away and replace them.)

---

**Related questions**

- [Finger print scanner with webusb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59576300/finger-print-scanner-with-webusb)

Comment: You can use the [WebUSB API](https://whatwebcando.today/usb.html) to send and receive data from the USB device. What the actual data must be depends solely on the device - so you will need the device manual.

Answer (score 0):

With WebUSB, without clear documentation for the "DigitalPersona 4500" device and what USB commands this device supports, it's really hard **but** still possible with lucky guessing. I strongly recommend getting the device.

Check out https://web.dev/devices-introduction/ for tips on how do this.
TLDR;

- [Watch Exploring WebUSB and its exciting potential](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpfZ8Nj3uiE) from Suz Hinton.
- You can also reverse-engineer this device by capturing raw USB
  traffic and inspecting [USB descriptors](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml) with external tools like
  Wireshark and built-in browser tools such as the internal page
  `about://usb-internals` in Chromium-based browsers.